# Ember cannot find existing component

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, frontend

I had a problem while working with Ember for the first time.

I created a component using `ember g component general-container`
It has created file with the name `general-container.hbs`

Now, when I try to use `<GeneralContainer>` tag, it gives a blank page and an error
`` Uncaught Error: Attempted to resolve `general-container`, which was expected to be a component, but nothing was found. ``

I have found nothing on this in the Internet, either I search badly or there's really nothing about this.

Edit: I was asked about the version. I was using

```
ember-cli 4.4.0 (already downgraded to 4.3.0)

ember-source is 4.4.1

windows is Windows NT 10 Pro x64 21H1 (19043.1645)
```

Comment: That's weird. Usually it works as expected. What version do you use btw?

Comment: is this in an addon or app? are you using ember-source 4.4.1? (4.4.0 had a bug related to generating files)

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli That's app, I actually use ember-cli 4.4.0
Looks like that's the reason why it doesn't work.

For some reason, another project generated similar component without any problems. I'll try to update and if it works, I'll mention this in an answer =)

Comment: @AndreyStukalin I cannot ping more that one at once, so the previous comment also has an answer. =)

Comment: Okay, I just realised that downgrading ember-cli won't help, as I was said that ember-source had a bug like this. I'm just trying to uninstall whole ember and reinstall it with newer version 4.4.1. I'm sorry for this, as I'm really new in node.js and other js-related stuff, so I might not understand something in this whole thing. Right now it's already too late, so I'll try to reinstall ember tomorrow morning, as it seems more tricky than expected. Thanks a lot for your help, I think this might work, but I also think that this might be because of me mistyping something.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
I just found out that I'm using 4.4.1 ember-source (I found that mentioned in build-metadata.json)
I think the problem is probably in code of mine. If I don't find the reason of the problem, I'll make it public in Github and add link (if my reputation will allow me to do so) to this repo in the question or just add it as code in question. Again, thanks a lot for your help! =)